# A Doublet's stream function

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, fluid

We were learning about superpositions of potential flows.

so,

$$\Psi_{doublet}  = \Psi_{source} + \Psi_{sink}$$

where: $\Psi_{source} = \frac{Q'}{2\pi}\theta_1$, and $\Psi_{sink} = \frac{-Q'}{2\pi}\theta_2$

I then expect:  $\Psi_{doublet} = \frac{Q'}{2\pi}(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$

but final form we were given was, $$\Psi_{doublet} = \frac{-Q'}{2\pi}(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$$

I have no clue as to where that extra minus sign is coming from.

Thank you guys kindly for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the source in this case is `θ2` since the sign convention normally is `-Q` for inward flow. This site https://www.ecourses.ou.edu/cgi-bin/eBook.cgi?doc=&topic=fl&chap_sec=07.3&page=theory provides an example where `θ2` is the source angular displacement.